# submeter form com vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
 Estou tentando submeter este form, mas da erro na hora de fazer o post. O meu objeto está vazio então a api não deixa inserir no banco e da erro. Gostaria de ajuda para saber por que os dados do form não estão sendo atribuidos no meu objeto produto. Por que está indo vazio? Sou iniciante em vue, agradeço!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Transcreva o código para a formatação de código do StackOverFlow

Comment: no lugar de `console.log('Não funcionou')`, coloque `console.log(response)`, e então, adicione o que vier a aparecer a sua pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou te dizer o que eu fiz, primeiro eu realizei uma instalação limpa de um novo projeto com o comando `vue init webpack my-project`.

Em seguida, copiei o código enviado nas imagens (o que fica aqui um conselho, não poste imagens e sim o código, para que fique mais fácil das pessoas ajudarem a resolver o problema), instalei o [Vue-resource](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource), pois presumo que é o que você está utilizando.

Feito isto, para realizar o POST, criei um mock no [MockAPI](http://www.mockapi.io/) com a rota produtos e o mesmo JSON que você está enviando no formulário, e aparentemente está funcionando.

```
<template>
  <div class="formup">
    <h1>Cadastro de Produtos</h1>
    <form class="createform" v-on:submit.prevent="insert">
      <input type="text" v-model="produto.codigoDeBarra"
      placeholder="Código de Barra" required="required" />
      <br>
      <input type="text" v-model="produto.estoque"
      placeholder="Quantidade" required="required" />
      <br>
      <input type="text" v-model="produto.nome"
      placeholder="Descrição do produto" required="required" />
      <br>
      <input type="text" v-model="produto.valorUn"
      placeholder="Valor uniário" required="required" />
      <br>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large"
      >Enviar</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
const url = 'https://5ae67b7736a18b00144e39a8.mockapi.io/produtos'

export default {
  name: 'CreateProducts',
  data () {
    return {
      produto: {
        nome: '',
        codigoDeBarra: '',
        estoque: '',
        valorUn: ''
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    insert () {
      console.log(this.produto)

      this.$http.post(url, this.produto)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response, 'funcionou')
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error, 'nao funcionou')
        })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Resultado da resposta após o POST:

[image: objeto]

[image: resposta]

Tente com estas informações, caso esteja ocorrendo problemas ainda, pode ser algo que está havendo no seu back-end que você está utilizando ou alguma outra parte do projeto que pode estar afetando isto por algum motivo, bem como se você está de fato utilizando o Vue-resouce ou não, etc.

Comment: Oi, fiz do jeito que você demonstrou e deu tudo ok. Realmente o problema é na API. Muito obrigada pela resposta, e pelas dicas de como usar o stackoverflow!!